C# Print paper size correct in 32 bit but not in 64 bit
I want to print an image with a specific paper size (the printer will cut off the paper automatically). When executing this code in 32 bit, it works perfectly. When executing this in 64 bit, my paper size (in code) seems correct but the printer cuts off the paper for the default paper size.
How can I resolve this problem?
var pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += PrintThreeImagesPage;
PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
printerSettings.PrinterName = "IP60 Photo";

pd.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = GetCustomPaperSize(printerSettings, 608, 258);
pd.Print();

private static PaperSize GetCustomPaperSize(PrinterSettings printerSettings, int width, int height)
{
    PaperSize? paperSize = null;

    foreach (PaperSize size in printerSettings.PaperSizes)
    {
        if (size.Width == width && size.Height == height)
        {
            paperSize = size;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (paperSize == null)
    {
        // If the custom paper size doesn't exist, create a new one
        Type type = typeof(PaperSize);
        paperSize = (PaperSize)type.InvokeMember("Custom",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, printerSettings, new object[] { "Custom", width, height });
    }

    return paperSize;
}

Update:
When I change the printer paper size in the Windows settings, the printed result is correct. I can assume that the C# code is not able to change this value on x64. Would it be possible to change that?

Why do you use reflection instead of calling the public PaperSize(String, Int32, Int32) conbstructor? You can then use the Add method of the PrinterSettings.PaperSizes Property to add the custom paper size. Or am I missing something?

I have tried this but no further success.
        var pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += PrintThreeImagesPage;
        PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        printerSettings.PrinterName = "IP60 Photo";

        pd.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
        var papersize = new PaperSize("Custom", 608, 258);
        printerSettings.PaperSizes.Add(papersize);
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = papersize;
        pd.Print();

